# Generating nested tree with full paths (URLS) and values from the database

Tags: php, mysql, url, tree, nested

I work on this issue since yesterday. More specifically - I have some values ​​in the database, which look as follows:

```
____________________________________
| id | parentId |   name   |  url  |
------------------------------------
| 1  |     0    | Nieuws   | url_1 |
------------------------------------
| 2  |     0    | Reviews  | url_2 |
------------------------------------
| 3  |     0    | Meuk     | url_3 |
------------------------------------
| 4  |     1    | Games    | url_4 |
------------------------------------
| 5  |     1    | Internet | url_5 |
------------------------------------
| 6  |     5    | Browsers | url_6 |
------------------------------------
```

I would like to see generated tree on the basis of these values. Target shape should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="url_1">Nieuws</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="url_1/url_4">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="url_1/url_5">Internet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="url_1/url_5/url_6">Browsers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="url_2">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="url_3">Meuk</a></li>
</ul>
```

It's important for me to have all the slashes inside the tree (full path with all the parents & children).

I would like to add, that I found the code on this page: http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/317/formatting-a-multi-level-menu-using-only-one-query.html but I can not redo it in such a manner as described above. I'll be very grateful for any help, because the application deadline is approaching very fast :(

Comment: Help with what? What *specific* problems are you running into when coding it?

Comment: how to add all the values inside the [href] - all parents urls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one modification. I think this way is much simpler. Instead of using an array to store the URL, I pass a string as an argument (containing the base url).

```php
// menu builder function, parentId 0 is the root 
function buildMenu($parentId, $menuData, $urlRoot) 
{ 
    $html = ''; 

    if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId])) 
    {
    $html = '<ul>'; 
    foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId) 
    { 
        $url   = $urlRoot . $itemId['url'] . '/';
        $html .= '<li><a href="$url">' . $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'] . '</a>'; 

        // find childitems recursively 
        $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData, $url); 

        $html .= '</li>'; 
    } 
    $html .= '</ul>'; 
    } 

    return $html; 
} 

// output the menu 
echo buildMenu(0, $menuData, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the function in your link, if you add url to the query, something like this should work:

```
<?php
// menu builder function, parentId 0 is the root
function buildMenu($parentId, $menuData, $nodes=false)
{
    $html = '';

    if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId]))
    {
        $html = '<ul>';
        if($nodes === false){
            $nodes = array();
        } elseif(!is_array($nodes)) {
            $nodes = array($nodes);
        } else {
            $nodes[] = $menuData['items'][$parentId]['url'];
        }
        foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId)
        {
            $html .= '<li><a href="/' . implode('/', $nodes) . '">';
            $html .= $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'] . '</a>';

            // find childitems recursively
            $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData, $nodes);

            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        array_pop($nodes);
    }

    return $html;
}

// output the menu
echo buildMenu(0, $menuData);
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible, that I've got the error: "[] operator not supported for strings in..." ? It refers to this line $nodes[] = $menuData

Comment: @Jakub you aren't supposed to pass anything in for the third parameter, the default value false is expected. I added a fix.